# HOW do I load a Javascript call in a Joomla module BACKEND?

Tags: javascript, joomla, backend, parameters

I'm developing a simple module fo Joomla 2.5. Everything is almost done, but I have a series of form fields in the module params backend, which I would like to hide when a specific checkbox is clicked on... I have the function made, it's just a loop with a document.getElementblablablabla.style.display = 'none', but how can I load the JS and attach the function to the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Quick solution!

you can include all your script inside your module XML files as normal script.
for this method you can use the description tag of [XML file like this](http://www.walkswithme.net/html-tags-inside-module-or-plugin-description-in-joomla)

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">

//Your javascript code(s)

</script>
]]>
</description>
```

This method work fine for Joomla version but its not a professional method. If you prefer more standard way you have to use param from [php file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/314/module-params-custom-validation-is-possible) or [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type)

Hope its helps..